# Unified distance measure to use in different implementations of OpenCV feature matching?

Tags: opencv, distance, matching

I'm trying to do some key feature matching in OpenCV, and for now I've been using `cv::DescriptorMatcher::match` and, as expected, I'm getting quite a few false matches.

Before I start to write my own filter and pruning procedures for the extracted matches, I wanted to try out the `cv::DescriptorMatcher::radiusMatch` function, which should only return the matches closer to each other than the given `float maxDistance`.

I would like to write a wrapper for the available OpenCV matching algorithms so that I could use them through an interface which allows for additional functionalities as well as additional extern (mine) matching implementations.

Since in my code, there is only one concrete class acting as a wrapper to OpenCV feature matching (similarly as `cv::DescriptorMatcher`, it takes the name of the specific matching algorithm and constructs it internally through a *factory method*), I would also like to write **a universal method to implement** matching utilizing `cv::DescriptorMatcher::radiusMatch` that would work for all the different matcher and feature choices (I have a similar wrapper that allows me to change between different OpenCV feature detectors and also implement some of my own).

Unfortunately, after looking through the OpenCV documentation and the `cv::DescriptorMatcher` interface, I just can't find any information about the *distance measure* used to calculate the actual distance between the matches. I found a pretty good matching example [here](http://public.cranfield.ac.uk/c5354/teaching/dip/opencv/lecture_demos/c++/surf_feature_matching.cpp) using Surf features and descriptors, but I did not manage to understand the actual meaning of a specific value of the argument.

Since I would like to compare the results I'd get when using different feature/descriptor combinations, I would like to know what kind of distance measure is used (and if it can easily be changed), so that I can use something that makes sense with *all the combinations* I try out.

Any ideas/suggestions?

**Update**

I've just printed out the feature distances I get when using `cv::DescriptorMatcher::match` with various feature/descriptor combinations, and what I got was:

- MSER/SIFT order of magnitude: 100
- SURF/SURF order of magnitude: 0.1
- SURF/SIFT order of magnitude: 50
- MSER/SURF order of magnitude: 0.2

From this I can conclude that whichever distance measure is applied to the features, it is definitely not normalized. Since I am using OpenCV's and my own interfaces to work with different feature extraction, descriptor calculation and matching methods, I would like to have some argument for `::radiusMatch` that I could use with all (most) of the different combinations. (I've tried matching using `BruteForce` and `FlannBased` matchers, and while the matches are slightly different, the discances between the matches are on the same order of magnitude for each of the combinations).

---

Some context:

I'm testing this on two pictures acquired from a camera mounted on top of a (slow) moving vehicle. The images should be around 5 frames (1 meter of vehicle motion) apart, so most of the features should be visible, and not much different (especially those that are far away from the camera in both images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnitude of the distance is indeed dependent on the type of feature used. That is because some specialized feature descriptors also come with a specialized feature matcher that makes optimal use of the descriptor. If you want to obtain weights for the match distances of different feature types, your best bet is probably to make a training set of a dozen or more 1:1 matches, unleash each feature detector/matcher on it, and normalize the distances so that each detector has an average distance of 1 over all matches. You can then use the obtained weights on other datasets.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the following function in `features2d.hpp` in opencv library.

```
template<class Distance> void BruteForceMatcher<Distance>::commonRadiusMatchImpl()
```

Usually we use `L2` distance to measure distance between matches. It depends on the descriptor you use. For example, `Hamming` distance is useful for the Brief descriptor since it counts the bit differences between two strings.